# Can a java program connect to a DB when MySql Workbench is NOT running?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-workbench

I am currently making a piece of software as a project in college. I have my program hooked up to a database to store and retrieve information about students after they enroll. I was bored and clicked on the JAR file while i did **not** have workbench opened, but i could still log in to the system and retrieve information.

My lecturer told us, during the lecture about implementing a database, that we needed workbench up and running to achieve the maximum functionality. Was she wrong?

Comment: The simple answer is of course **YES**

Comment: @RiggsFolly I want to know how though?

Comment: You had better show us some actual code then, unless you want us to just keep **guessing**

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't think we need any code at all to figure this out...

Comment: @RiggsFolly This wasn't a question about programming, this was a question on how did the my program connect to the server when Workbench wasn't running. Which i was told that it was required.

Comment: Ok, so I guess she ment that to create the database and the tables inside the database you shoudl use WorkBench, therefore you have to have it installed so you can do that step

Comment: She specifically said "workbench must be open to access the DB".

Comment: @Aaronward It must be open to access it via the workbench, of course. But not to be accessed via another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a MySQL (or any other SQL) server is running, you can always connect to it (technically, of course you may need username/password and you may have to care about firewall restrictions). The MySQL Workbench is just another client that connects to the database, so it is not needed to be running to let a Java program establish a connection to the database.

---

Thoughts: I think your lecturer meant that you will not be able to check whether all your queries where executed correctly when not having another view onto the database to check the data.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL server is running regardless of whether or not MySQL Workbench (the database administration tool) is active/running or not. Those are two different things.

Moreover, you are doing the same that the tools is doing: connecting to the running MySQL server instance in order to do some actions.

Comment: This is more of a comment rather than an actual answer. You may find it just attracts downvotes!